# Java Socket Chat, some messages not sending

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I recently started learning out Sockets and other Networking Stuff like that works, I made a simple Chat program with a GUI, it works somewhat, the problem is that If order the message to send to the server the client must put the same message twice, and if the server sends a message, the client must reply once.

Heres my Client/Server Class:

```
package org.codingllamas.Chat;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;

public class SC {

static Socket clientSocket;
static BufferedReader inFromServer;
static DataOutputStream outToServer;

public static void clientSetup(int port,String ip) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
     String modifiedSentence;
     Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Connected to </b>" + ip + ":" + port + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
     while (true) {
     ///BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     clientSocket = new Socket(ip,port);
     outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
     inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
     modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();     
     //System.out.println(modifiedSentence);
     Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Server: </b>" + modifiedSentence + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
     //clientSocket.close();
     }
}

public static void clientSend(String msg) throws IOException, BadLocationException{
    outToServer.writeBytes(msg + "\r");
    outToServer.flush();
    Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>You: </b>" + msg + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
}

static ServerSocket welcomeSocket;
static Socket connectionSocket;
static BufferedReader inFromClient;
static DataOutputStream outToClient;

public static void serverSetup(int port) throws Exception {
    String clientSentence;
    welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Server Started on port: " + port + "</b><br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
    while(true){
       connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
       inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
       clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
       outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

       Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Parther: </b>" + inFromClient.readLine() + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
    }
}

public static void serverSend(String msg) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
    //DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    outToClient.writeBytes(msg + "\r");
    outToClient.flush();

    Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>You: </b>" + msg + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
}
}
```

And a picture:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use a `DataOutputStream`, use a `BufferedWriter.`
2. Don't create a new socket per `modifiedSentence?`: use a single `Socket` for the life of the client, and loop reading lines, and close the socket when you get null.
3. Don't read a single line from the client per `accept():` start a new thread to read lines like the client does now.

Comment: I changed my code to this: http://pastebin.com/FjDSvZBf
The client gets all the messages that the server sends, but for some weird reason, the server is only getting every other message that the client sends. (i.e. Client sends "1","2","3","4","5","6", Server gets "2","4","6")